# Migrating from C18 to XC8 ADC Conversion Issue

Tags: pic, sensor, adc, timing, xc8

I'm working with Pic18f6622 and migrating my program into XC8 compiler. Before I'm using the C18 compiler ADC conversion was working just fine, but in new compiler ADC returns me 11 bits value and the expected value is far more different. Maybe the timing is not enough to allow ADC to work healthy, but I couldn't be sure.
EDIT #I'm using external 10Mhz crystal#

The "analogval" value returns as 077C, but should be 01DB or close to this. By the way I'm reading PT100 value. I'm sharing the snippet below:

```
#include <xc.h>
#pragma config OSC = HSPLL, WDT = OFF, WDTPS = 512, BOREN = SBORDIS, BORV = 2, PWRT = ON, LVP = OFF,  MCLRE = OFF

unsigned int analogval;

void AnalogReader(void) {
  while( ADCON0bits.GO != 0 ) continue;

  analogval = ADRESH;
  analogval <<= 8;
  analogval += ADRESL;

  ADCON0 = 0x10; // select first AN0 to AN4
  ADCON0bits.ADON = 1;
  ADCON0bits.GO = 1;
}


void InitDevice(void) {
  TRISA = 0b00111111;
  TRISB = 0b00000000;
  TRISD = 0b00000000;
  TRISF = 0b00111111; // F0~F3 analog input


  // an0 an1 an2 *an3-NC* an4 an5 an6 an7 an8 analog, internal vref+ vref-
  ADCON1 = 0b00000110;
  ADCON2 = 0b10110010; // right justified, 16 tad acquisition, fosc/32
  ADCON0 = 0b00000001; // enable adc


  INTCON2 = 0b11111000; /// pull-up disabled

  RCONbits.IPEN = 0;  // interrupt priority not used
  INTCONbits.INT0IE = 1; // int0 interrupt enabled
  INTCONbits.PEIE = 1; // peripheral interrupts enabled
  INTCONbits.GIE = 0; // interrupts disabled
}

void InitTimeBase(void) {
  T3CON = 0x00;
  T1CON = 0x00;
  CCP1CON = 0b00001011; // Compare mode(RC2 OUTPUT): reset TMR1, set CCP1IF

  CCPR1H = 0x03;
  CCPR1L = 0xE8; // 1000 increments(=instructions)
  // Instruction cycle: 1/(40Mhz/4) = 0.1us
  // 1000 instructions = 0.1ms = 10KHz

  TMR1H = 0x00;
  TMR1L = 0x00;

  T1CONbits.TMR1ON = 1; //start timer

  PIE1bits.CCP1IE = 1; // TMR1 interrupt enable bit
  INTCONbits.PEIE = 1; // Overflow interrupt enable bit
  INTCONbits.GIE = 0; //Global interrupt enable bit
}

void main(void) {
  InitDevice();
  InitTimeBase();


  delay_ms(2000);  // custom delay


  do {
    if (PIR1bits.CCP1IF) { //10kHz  --> 1000 instruction.
      PIR1bits.CCP1IF = 0;

      /*
       * Bunch of operations
      */


      if (slot == 0)
        AnalogReader();
      if (slot == 1)
        // OP
      if (slot == 2)
        // OP
      if (slot == 3)
        //OP

      slot++;
      if (slot == 100) // slot 0..99 : Enter a slot each 10ms.
        slot = 0;

      //-----------------------------
      counter++;
      if (counter == 10000) {
        counter = 0; // 1 sec
      }

      if (counter > 5000) { //0.5 sec
        PORTBbits.LED1 = 1;
      } else { //0.5 sec
        PORTBbits.LED1 = 0;
      }
    }
  } while (1);
}
```

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Have you checked the analogue voltage on the the ADC pin is what you think it should be? Have you modified any of the code at all since switching from the old compiler?

Comment: Your result seems to be 4 times the expected result, as though the result were shifted left twice.  But I don't see a cause.

Comment: @DiBosco I've checked and it should be 01DB (2.44V), but as gbarry stated , the value is 4 times this one.

Comment: Sorry it should be 2.31V

Comment: I'd be looking at the disassembly to see what is really going on. Is it at all possible you're using the wrong processor header file and reading a different register to the one you think it is?

Comment: @DiBosco, I've checked the header, and added explicitly #include <pic18f6723.h> but still no luck. Also I've checked the Vref it's also Pic's voltage which is 4.97 V.

Comment: So what is the disassembler saying? Is it doing what you think it should be?

Comment: I don't think I had the issue with registers, for example:       !  ADCON0 = 0x10; // select first AN0 to AN4  
0x1F3AC: MOVLW 0x10     
0x1F3AE: MOVWF ADCON0, ACCESS    
!  ADCON0bits.ADON = 1;     
0x1F3B0: BSF ADCON0, 0, ACCESS    
!  ADCON0bits.GO = 1;     
0x1F3B2: BSF ADCON0, 1, ACCESS

Comment: This maybe gives a clue, when I ground the analog pin that I've read, the value becomes 0x0001 and when I give 5V to the pin it becomes 0x0FFF (but this should be 0x03FF afaik)

Comment: @gbarry I've tried to give 3.3V to the analog pin, and guess what, I've read 0a83 which is 0a83/4 = 02a0 and this is equivalent of 3.28 or smt.

Comment: Why do you disable and then immediately re-enable the ADC in your AnalogReader function?

Comment: Why would you try #include <18f672**3**.h> when you're using a 672**2**? The ..23 has a 12-bit ADC while your ..22 only has a 10-bit. Are you sure you've selected the correct device?

Comment: ... or are you actually using a ..23 - which would perfectly explain the apparently 12-bit result you're seeing?

Comment: @brhans now that explains why I'm looking at the wrong datasheet, indeed my device is 18f6723, but I'm looking at 18f8722 family datasheet which has 10 bit ADC, thank you.